# Generating form inputs in AngularJS with non-uniform structure

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to generate a form where each entry is a rule which either enabled or disabled.

I want it to look like:

```
[X] Color is blue
[X] Size is at least [ 50 ]
[X] Speed is at least [ 20 ] for [ 7 ] [ minutes ]

[ Submit ]
```

where [X] denotes a checkbox [ number ] is a spinbox/edit and [ text ] is a listbox.

I want to generate this ruleset from a template. The main question is how this non-uniform template expansion would better be done in AngularJS? Is it suitable at all for this kind of tasks?

The source model for this looks something like (Coffeescript syntax for brevity):

```
color_blue: 
  template: "Color is {{color}}"
  params:
    color: 
      type: "list"
      values: ["red", "blue" ]
      default: 1

size_at_least:
  template: "Size is at least {{size}}"
  params:
    size: 
      type: "Number"
      min: 30
      max: 60
      default: 50
speed_at_least:
  template: "Speed is at least {{speed}} for {{time}} {{time_units}}"
  params:
    speed: 
      type: "Number"
      min: 0
      max: 60
      default: 0
    time: 
      type: "int"
      min: 0
      max: 20
      default: 7
    unit: 
      type: "list"
      values: ["seconds", "minutes", "hours" ]
      default: 1
```

I can definitely use JQuery and generate these rules easily but I'm currently learning AngularJS and would prefer learn something from this practical task.